# Dell PowerVault MD1000 Keeps Shutting Down

Tags: debian, storage, dell, shutdown

I have a Powervault MD1000 that has been running for over a year with no issues, but within the past couple weeks, every few days the enclosure powers down and it and the server has to be restarted to bring it back on line.  The server runs Debian  but I can't imagine this has much to do with the problem, because the enclosure actually powers off.  (No lights on the front are on, but the power lights on the power supplies remain on and green).  This has happened a few times now, but I've never been able to catch it happening.  When viewing the virtual drive in the PERC control BIOS screen, the RAID status shows as optimal, and all SMART statuses are fine.  I tried to swap the storage controller modules, as I am only using one, but that didn't seem to fix it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The Dell OMSA log is empty, but the syslog showed "Jan 16 09:08:35 SAN-1 kernel: [ 2362.584045] megaraid_sas 0000:0e:00.0: MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware" when it happened.

Comment: Have you reviewed the MD1000 logs? Have you contacted Dell support?

Comment: @joeqwerty Oh, sorry.  The OSMA logs show no errors, but the syslog shows  Jan 16 09:08:35 SAN-1 kernel: [ 2362.584045] megaraid_sas 0000:0e:00.0: MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware thousands of times.

Comment: Maybe it shutdown due to increased system temperature. Have you checked that? Anyway, if the unit is under an active support contract, contact DELL for assistance.

Comment: @shodanshok how would I check if that was the cause of the shutdown?  I'm not suggesting it's an invalid theory,  because I'm going to try to test it today,  but the poweredge  2950 that the MD1000 is connected to is right above it is running right in the middle of the green temperature wise,  so why would this unit be shutting down for thermal protection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using both power supplies in your MD1000? Also are the fans spinning on the power supplies at normal speed or are thy spinning slower?  Also was the only error showing in OMSA the SAS error? 
If all the fans are spinning & power supplies are green then I would check to make sure that that the plugs are securely fitted & if available then I would swap then plug to a different plug if available to see if the issue happens again. 
Please let us know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Both power supplies are in, and it seems the fans are at normal speed.  In OMSA, the temperatures are stable between 22 and 25 degrees C.  I reseated the power supplies and dusted the connectors.  Fingers crossed.